# How to convert UIBezierPath to GMSPolyline swift3

Tags: swift3

I am trying to draw a curved line in google maps. For this I am using UIBezierPath. Now I have the lat and long value but I want to convert UIBezierPath to GMSPolyline. How can I do that?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. The two systems (UIBezierPath and GMSPolyLine) work in different coordinate systems and different spatial systems. They don’t really convert from one to another. Why not just create the GMSPath and use that instead of creating the UIBezierPath?

Comment: I want to create an curved poly line in google map. is there any way